# Fill Angular Material 2 tab with flex-layout

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I'm attempting to create a tabbed app using [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2), and [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). I can't figure out how to get the content of the tab to expand to fill the screen.

This is what I see:
[image]

My code for the layout is as follows, and includes a toolbar and footer.

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="column">

  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    Toolbar
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-tab-group>

    <md-tab label="Tab 1">
      <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" style="background-color:lightblue;padding:10px">
        <div style="background:lightgreen;">This should stay as it is</div>
        <div fxFlex style="background:lightgray;">This should expand so it fills the majorty of the screen</div>
      </div>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Tab 2">
      <h1>some content page 2</h1>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Tab 3">
      <h1>some content page 3</h1>
    </md-tab>

  </md-tab-group>

  <div>Footer</div>
</div>
```

I have placing `fxFlex` at various places and creating extra `div` containers, all without any success. Any ideas what I should do?

Plunkr created here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eU413bX36I6aZFRTs6cg?p=preview

Comment: Please use the angular tag for angular2+ questions.

Comment: Try the [following](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gu1zb9zAasba5kVj5VA5?p=preview) and see if it's what you're looking for. I can write an explanation if that works for you.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselskyThanks, yes that seems to work. Much appreciated!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky if you write up the explanation in an answer I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you'd need to do to get the material tabs content, which is wrapped in `div.mat-tab-body-content` full height for your example:

1. While you had `html`/`body` set to `100%`, `<material-app>` was not expanding to the full height. Using `:host { min-height: 100vh; }` in a linked component stylesheet, ensured it expanding to full height
2. A similar issue occurs with the `div.mat-tab-body-wrapper` that is generated when using `<md-tab>` and wraps all the tab content. Using CSS, either in the component styles or somewhere globally such as `style.css`, it would need to be set to `flex: 1;`, which will have it take as much remaining space as possible. `height: 100%;` would work as well.
3. Finally the first/child `div` inside of `div.mat-tab-body-content` which doesn't have a class would need `height: 100%;` to take up remaining height now that all it's parents, including `div.mat-tab-body-wrapper` and `div.mat-tab-body` are stretching to full height.

With this approach, it should adjust to dynamic toolbar and footer sizes.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The plunker doesn't work any more, but here is a stackblitz that demonstrates the solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-httpclient-example-dxrppy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

Use a minimum height for your tab group in case you need all tabs the same height

```
<md-tab-group style='min-height:800px;'>
```